# C char arrays and pointers - merge of mergesort

Tags: c, pointers, merge, segmentation-fault, pipe

I'm trying to implement merge by reading characters from a pipe and then putting them into a result string.  I keep getting a segmentation error and am having trouble debugging the source of the problem.  When I remove the call to this function the problem goes away so I have a feeling something here is incorrect:

MAX_LENGTH is set to 1024 and I'm only sorting about 30 characters so I should have room to spare I believe.

```
int merge(char *result, int *leftpipefd, int *rightpipefd) {
char left[MAX_LENGTH/2];
char right[MAX_LENGTH/2];
int leftpos = 0;
int rightpos = 0;
int resultpos = 0;

read(leftpipefd[READ_END], left, MAX_LENGTH/2);
read(rightpipefd[READ_END], right, MAX_LENGTH/2);

int leftlen = strlen(left);
int rightlen = strlen(right);

while (leftpos < leftlen || rightpos < rightlen) {
    if (leftpos < leftlen && rightpos < rightlen) {
        if (left[leftpos] <= right[rightpos]) {
            result[resultpos] = left[leftpos];
            resultpos++;
            leftpos++;
        } else {
            result[resultpos] = right[rightpos];
            resultpos++;
            rightpos++;
        }
    } else if (leftpos <  leftlen) {
        result[resultpos] = right[rightpos];
        resultpos++;
        rightpos++;
    } else if (rightpos <  rightlen) {
        result[resultpos] = left[leftpos];
        resultpos++;
        leftpos++;
    }
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try using a debugger. What values are the calls to strlen() returning? Are your `left` and `right` "strings" null-terminated?

Comment: What is the best way to debug this?  My stdin and stdout are attached to pipes in this process so I don't know how to print.

Comment: @Deathcalibur "use a debugger."  Debugger doesn't mean just write print statements, it's an actual program, e.g. gdb

Comment: @djechlin Using gdb after reading up on it a bit really helped, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading N characters into a buffer of length N, how do you expect the `strlen` function to work properly... it needs at least a buffer of `N+1` since there must be room for the terminating `\0` character. When that's not there, who knows what happens next...

Answer (score 0):

Several things...

From http://linux.die.net/man/2/read ...

> read() attempts to read up to count bytes from file descriptor fd into the buffer starting at buf.
>   If count is zero, read() returns zero and has no other results. If count is greater than SSIZE_MAX, the result is unspecified.

What is MAX_LEN?  Is it larger than SSIZE_MAX?  If so, you have undefined behavior.

If the read()s don't have input, you won't be reading anything... and the buffers, which you haven't initialized, will not have changed.  You should initialize your buffers.

From the same page...

> On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

If read fails, your buffer is still undefined/uninitialized, but you don't detect/handle this situation.  You need some error handling code immediately after the read()s.

Also, on the same man page, there's no indicator that your buffers from read() are null terminated.  As Floris points out, this means that your strlen()s may continue reading past the end of your allocated buffers.

> while (leftpos < leftlen || rightpos < rightlen) {

This line may be in error.  If leftpos >= leftlen but rightpos < rightpos you'll enter the body of the while block.  You'll probably start accessing invalid memory that way.  Do you really need `&&`?